# Onclick window.location changes the updated css property using my javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

The css property which is updated in the javascript does not stay when on click is triggered from html.

```
Javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
function Redirect() {
window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5000/testlink");
document.getElementsById('tab1').style.cssText = 'color:blue; font-size:22px;'}
</script>
HTML:
<input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab1" aria-controls="rawdata"onclick="Redirect()">
```

Raw Data

Once the tag is clicked, the css property changes appears and goes away once the windows refreshes

Comment: That's how it should be. isn't it?? you are already redirecting to different page then how would you expect the color to stay? and its **getElementById** not **getElementsById**.

Comment: You're redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:5000/testlink what do you except?

Comment: thats how the internet and requests work

Answer (score 1):

Once the radio button is selected, you can set it to a local storage and then check it when the page is first loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var hasClick = localStorage.getItem("hasClick");
   if(hasClick == true){
   document.getElementsById('tab1').style.cssText = 'color:blue; font-size:22px;'}}



Javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
function Redirect() {
sessionStorage.setItem("hasClick", true);
document.getElementsById('tab1').style.cssText = 'color:blue; font-size:22px;'};
window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:5000/testlink");    
</script>
HTML:
<input type="radio" name="tabset" id="tab1" aria- 
controls="rawdata"onclick="Redirect()">
```

Answer (score 0):

That wont work, you will need to save these changes somewhere, for example:

- Cookies
- Local storage
- Database

you save your change somewhere in these 3 saving options and then write a javascript code on window load to check if there is a color setting availaible and then change your tag color

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would prefer to do ajax? This way you can make a http request to the backoffice without the lost of your page state. Then your css property change will apply after your request.